# How to efficiently hit the database for a related field in REST serializer?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a complex architecture for my database and I'm having troubles writting the corresponding REST API.

Context: I am requesting various informations on a public API every hour, including data I want to keep history for.

Here's the models I am using

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PlayerStatsHistory(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey('Player', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_refresh = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ...
```

This way, I can store every change in the stats of each user.
I wrote 2 serializers one for `Player` and one for `PlayerStatsHistory`. The easiest one works fine

```
class PlayerStatsSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerStatsHistory
        fields = ('last_refresh', ...)
```

But when I need to request the latest stats for one player I'm getting confused :

```
class PlayerSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    details = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_details(self, obj):
        return PlayerStatsSerializer(PlayerStatsHistory.objects.filter(player=obj).order_by('-last_refresh').first()).data

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('name', 'details')
```

This works fine, but will hit database at each player provided to the `PlayerSerializer` and I feel like I'm doing it wrong.

How can I improve this solution ?

Comment: Generally such things are done by overriding `get_queryset` with `.prefetch_related()` in your API view class, but I'm not sure it can be easily done via a prefetch with your specific query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best you can do is first get the id of the last `PlayerStatsHistory` of each Player(using group_by):

```
latest_stats_history_pks = PlayerStatsHistory.objects.values('player').annotate(max_id=models.Max('id')).values_list('max_id', flat=True)
```

(it has a problem, it uses all of the players if you are using pagination you don't need all of them, in that case, prefetch without filtering its queryset should be fine)

then only prefetch this values on your `Player` queryset, so:

```
       queryset = Player.objects.all().prefetch_related(models.Prefetch(
        'playerstatshistory_set',
        queryset=PlayerStatsHistory.objects.filter(pk__in=latest_stats_history_pks), to_attr='last_stat_list'))
```

so finally your `get_queryset` method in your view should be like:

```
def get_queryset(self):

    latest_stats_history_pks = PlayerStatsHistory.objects.values('player').annotate(max_id=models.Max('id')).values_list('max_id', flat=True)

    queryset = Player.objects.all().prefetch_related(models.Prefetch(
        'playerstatshistory_set',
        queryset=PlayerStatsHistory.objects.filter(pk__in=latest_stats_history_pks), to_attr='last_stat_list'))

    return queryset
```

and if you're using FBV, do something like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
def player_list(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        latest_stats_history_pks = PlayerStatsHistory.objects.values('player').annotate(max_id=models.Max('id')).values_list('max_id', flat=True)

        players = Player.objects.all().prefetch_related(models.Prefetch(
        'playerstatshistory_set',
        queryset=PlayerStatsHistory.objects.filter(pk__in=latest_stats_history_pks), to_attr='last_stat_list'))

        serializer = PlayerSerializer(players, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

also in your serializer, change that field as below:

```
class PlayerSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    details = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_details(self, obj):
        return {} if not obj.last_stat_list else PlayerStatsSerializer(obj.last_stat_list[-1]).data

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('name', 'details')
```

Comment: I'm currently using function based views, can you expand your answer on the View ?

Comment: I got `AttributeError at /api/player/42: 'Player' object has no attribute 'last_stat_list'`

Comment: can you add your view to the question?

Comment: My bad, I was actually requesting my previous endpoint and not yours